# How to solve the system of equations $y= 5x^2-2x$ and $y=10x+9 $?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations, quadratics

I am trying to solve this system of equations $y= 5x^2-2x$ and $y=10x+9$.

I have worked the problem out and I am lost could someone please explain it? I have a test tomorrow over this information.

Comment: Have you learned how to solve quadratic equations?

Comment: Thats what this is @JimmyK4542

Answer (score 0):

$$y=5x^2-2x$$ 
$$y=10x+9$$

Since both equations are equal to $y$ we have the following:

$$\Rightarrow 5x^2-2x=10x+9 \Rightarrow 5x^2-12x-9=0$$

To solve this you have to find the discriminant.

Can you continue?

Comment: How do you get -9?

Comment: From the equality $$5x^2-2x=10x+9$$ we get all the terms at the left side of the equation.

Comment: She subtracted $10x+9$ from both sides of the equation. Once you have a quadratic, you can try factoring.  (If that doesn't work, use the quadratic formula.)